# Recompile vim with the same features

Tags: linux, vim, compile, make

I want to recompile vim with the same features for a different linux distro. I only kept the source tar and I don't remember any of the arguments I gave `./configure` the first time. What's the easiest way to do this?

Do I have to manually compare the output of `./configure --help` and `vim --version`? Or is there a more automated method?

I originally deleted the source folder to save space. Is there a particular set of files I can save after running the configuration script so that I don't run into this issue in the future?

Comment: How long ago did you compile it? Is it possible the command would be in your shell's history file?  Otherwise, yes, you are going to have to recover the configuration options by hand.

Comment: It's been months since the last time I compiled vim, so it's definitely not in my history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normally not necessary to pick individual features; it should be sufficient to choose a feature set (e.g. `--with-features=big`) and list the desired language integrations (`--enable-pythoninterp`).

With that, you can easily recompile a new Vim version later. (If you update frequently, I'd consider writing an alias / small shell script to enapsulate the call.)

I wouldn't recommend saving the output of the `./configure` run, as the circumstances of Vim and/or your system configuration may change at any time (e.g. after a distribution update, the Python version may have changed).

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for you now, but a lot of people keep a script that will run configure with their desired options, so that you can re-run it every time. My personal method is a readme file that gives me a step-by-step in case I forget, and then I can just

```
`grep configure ../README`
```

To run the command itself.